# Access_token in php and javascript with Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, fbjs

I am having a problem integrating my game into Facebook. Upon reading about the documentation, I read that the best and most up-to-date way to communicate with FB from Flash is via the Facebook API on javascript. I call this to get all the ui dialogs and basic login information. Now, my flash games connects to a php to send and receive highscores like so:

scores.php?action=NEWSCORE&userId=123123123&score=100

scores.php?action=VIEW

scores.php?action=VIEWFRIENDS&userId=123123123

Now, in scores.php, when I set the VIEWFRIENDS action, I want the php to create the facebook query. I do this by adding

```
// Init the Facebook SDK
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
));

// Get the current user
$user = $facebook->getUser();

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$fbresponse = $facebook->api("/me/friends?fields=installed", array('access_token'=>$access_token.$access_token,));

if ($fbresponse)
{
    $friendsData = $fbresponse['data'];
    $friendsString = '';
    $friendCount = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($friendsData); $i++)
    {
        $friend = $friendsData[$i];

        if ($friend['installed'])
        {
            if ($friendCount > 0)
                $friendsString = $friendsString . ",";

            $friendsString = $friendsString . "'" . $friend['id'] . "'";                    $friendCount++;
        }
    }
    // Get the friends highscores
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Highscores WHERE FacebookId IN (" . $friendsString . ") ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT " . $scoresize ;
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

When doing this, all appears to work if I test it outside Facebook, but when I integrate it into my app, it throws the following error:

> ```
> <br />
> <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid access token signature.
>   thrown in <b>/home/public_html/mysite.org/games/myGameFacebook/fb-php-sdk/base_facebook.php</b>
> ```
>
> on line **1106**

I am trying to check whats happening and I have yet to find out what to do about it. I understand the access token is generated on Javascript when logging in by this code.

```
getLoginStatus:function() {
    log("getLoginStatus");
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {

            log("Logged in.");
            F.token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            F.getCurrentUserInfo();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            log("User did not authorize app");
        } else {
            log("Not logged in.");
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if(response.session) {
                    log("Logging successful.");
                    F.token = response.session.access_token;
                    F.getCurrentUserInfo();
                } else {
                    log("Logging failed.");
                }
            });
        }
    });
},
```

How can I resolve this issue? I've been trying to understand how to do it, but I've read its either impossible, or link to some unknown session variable that has never worked.

Answer (score 0):

You're concatenating the access token with itself in the call to $facebook->api

```
array('access_token'=>$access_token.$access_token,)
```

should look like:

```
array('access_token'=>$access_token,)
```

But I guess you should use an app access token to retrieve what you need, with a function like:

```
 // Helper function to get an APP ACCESS TOKEN
 function get_app_access_token($app_id, $app_secret) {
   $token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?'
     . 'client_id=' . $app_id
     . '&client_secret=' . $app_secret
     . '&grant_type=client_credentials';

   $token_response =file_get_contents($token_url);
   $params = null;
   parse_str($token_response, $params);
   return  $params['access_token'];
 }
```

You'll need to pass it the app secret that you can read on Facebook Developer App Page.